# Will flashing CyanogenMod reset the status of SIM lock on Nexus S?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-nexus-s, sim-unlocking

I have Samsung Google Nexus S (SIM unlocked) on Android KitKat. I am planning to install CyanogenMod 11 on it. The question is, will upgrading to CyanogenMod lock my SIM? Will I have to unlock it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will upgrading to CyanogenMod lock my Sim Again?

**Nope**!

CyanogenMod doesn't have anything to do with lock or unlock of sim cards.

But by the way, [isn't CyanogenMod 11 the same as KitKat?](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/CyanogenMod#/CyanogenMod_11)